How to trigger table update when email is successfully verified on laravel breeze?
So I have customized the users table on the default installation of Laravel Breeze, I want specific updates to the table rows when the email is successfully verified.  How to do it?  I don't really understand which files to change. I want the changes to trigger along with changes to the email_verified_at row.
I want the changes to trigger along with changes to the email_verified_at row

If you want to add extra actions on email verify request you can check app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerifyEmailController.php. Maybe here you can add extra logic according to business logic.

You can listen for the Verified event.
Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified

Check the docs for more info.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/verification#events
